# Installations on WSL?

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I use Python Anaconda and Visual Studio Code for Data Science and Machine Learning projects.

I want to learn how to use Windows Subsystem for Linux, and I have seen that tools such as Conda or Git can be installed directly there, but I don't quite understand the difference between a common Python Anaconda installation and a Conda installation in WSL.

Is one better than the other? Or should I have both? How should I integrate WSL into my work with Anaconda, Git, and VS Code? What advantages does it have or what disadvantages?

Help please, I hate not installing my tools properly and then having a mess of folders, environment variables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use conda it's better to install it directly on Windows rather than in WSL. Think of WSL as a virtual machine in your current PC, but much faster than you think.

It's most useful use would be as an alternate base for docker. You can run a whole lot of stuff with Windows integration from WSL, which includes VS Code. You can lauch VS code as if it is run from within that OS, with all native extension and app support.

You can also access the entire Windows filesystem from WSL and vice versa, so integrating Git with it won't be a bad idea

Comment: You'll find [Microsoft advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment#file-storage) is, for performance reasons, to use the WSL Linux filespace with Linux, and the Microsoft filespace with Windows. WSL is good because you get a fairly performant actual Linux implementation when there may be other factors constraining you to a Windows device (e.g. your company). And it's a great opportunity to learn Linux without leaving a familiar place. But really, you're better off going fully native to find out why Linux is so much better.